# The for each loop for the custom data type (ArrayList) with self implemented iterator does not run

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, iterator, custom-data-type

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ArrayList<Type> implements Iterable<Type> {
Type[] arr = (Type[]) new Object[10];
int size = 0;

//change capacity
public void newCapacity(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        int newIncreasedCapacity = arr.length * 2;
        arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, newIncreasedCapacity);
    } else if (i == 1) {
        int newDecreasedCapacity = arr.length / 2;
        arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, newDecreasedCapacity);
    }

}

// add an item
public void add(Type item) {
    if (size == arr.length) {
        newCapacity(0);
    }
    arr[size++] = item;   //increases size after appending
}

//remove an item
public Type remove(int index) {
    if (size <= arr.length / 4) {
        newCapacity(1);
    }

    Type removedItem = (Type) arr[index];
    for (int i = index; i < size - 1; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    size -= 1;

    return removedItem;

}

public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
    return new ArrayIterator(arr);
}

class ArrayIterator<Type> implements Iterator<Type> {
    private Type[] arrayList;

    public ArrayIterator(Type[] newArray) {
        arrayList = newArray;
    }


    // check if next element not null
    public boolean hasNext() {

        return (arrayList[size + 1] != null);
    }

    // next element
    public Type next() {
        if (arrayList[size + 1] != null) {
            return (arrayList[size + 1]);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

// Main Method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> new_arr = new ArrayList<>();
    new_arr.add(5);
    new_arr.add(7);
    new_arr.add(9);
    new_arr.remove(0);

    System.out.println(new_arr.size());
    for (int i : new_arr) {
        System.out.println(new_arr.size());
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
}
```

I implemented the code for a custom ArrayList and also implemented an iterator for my custom data type, but I am facing an issue.
So when i run the for each loop in the main method, the loop does not run and thus nothing is printed on the console.I have checked the array which is being used for the for-each loop is not empty.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should fix your Iterator to something like

```
class ArrayIterator<Type> implements Iterator<Type> {
    private Type[] arrayList;
    private int position;

    public ArrayIterator(Type[] newArray) {
        arrayList = newArray;
        position = 0;
    }


    // check if next element not null
    public boolean hasNext() {

        return (position != size);
    }

    // next element
    public Type next() {
        if (arrayList[position] != null) {
            return (arrayList[position++]);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You are using the position of the `size` of the array to calculate the `next()` and `hasNext()`, the `hasNext()` is always returning `null`.

Comment: Thank you!! That now runs perfectly. You are the best.